# How to point a domain to another subdomain?

Tags: web-hosting, domains, subdomain, nameserver

I'm really a newbie about this issues so excuse me if this is a rather dumb question, I'm trying to point a domain a client of mine bought to a sub-domain of mine, they're both from different companies, I'm not looking for a redirect but instead let's say his domain is www.clientdomain.com and mine is www.mydoamin.com I need to point dev.clientdomain.com to test.mydomain.com for example keeping the URL as it is, so when I visit the 'about' page it'd be dev.clientdomain.com/about instead of test.mydomain.com/about.

I hope it makes some sense, I have seen this done before but have no idea if its using .htaccess files or changing some configuration options in the host control panel, if so I assume each host has their way of doing this so a general example would be great to point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you name your hosting company and domain registration companies we will be able to give you a more precise answer.

Answer (score 1):

Parking a domain ontop of another domain is usually done using DNS plus some settings in the web server. Most hosting companies have an option in their control panels that allows you to easily park a domain on top of another. In addition to setting up on your host control panel you will need to edit the nameserver or DNS settings at the domain register.

If you name your hosting company and domain registration companies we will be able to give you a more precise answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the control panel wherever the client domain was registered; there should be an option to point it at wherever you want.

As an example, if I log into my control panel, I can select any domain and choose the directory I want it to point at, but I can also point it at a different site.

I believe you would just use the .htaccess if you actually did want a redirect.

Answer (score 0):

- Add `dev IN CNAME test.mydomain.com.` to clientdomain.com zone-definition
- As mentioned before, in site-hosting panel for test.mydomain.com define dev.clientdomain.com as alias