# How can I point a subdomain at another server?

Tags: mod-rewrite, dns, subdomain

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to point a domain to another subdomain?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/15035/how-to-point-a-domain-to-another-subdomain)

Is it possible to set up a subdomain to render content of another server?

Let's say I wanted google.domain.com to render google.com (for example).  Is this a matter of setting up a CNAME?  Mod-Rewrite?  How could I point it to another server?

I suppose it's similar to how wordpress.com allows their bloggers to use their own domain when on their hosted service.  But I'm not sure how they accomplish this in the background.

We can't do iframes.  And we've seen another example of someone using the same API to render the remotely hosted site on their own domain.

Answer (score 3):

CNAME works just fine.  So long as the target site sets up a ServerAlias to accommodate.